# Lazy initialization with singleton pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

Would the following code facilitate **lazy initialization**?
Or would the `singletonInstance` be created as soon as somebody includes the header (or even at program startup time)?

```
class SingletonClass
{
    private:
         SingletonClass();
        ~SingletonClass();

    public: 

        static const SingletonClass& Instance()
        {
            static SingletonClass singletonInstance;
            return singletonInstance; 
        }
};
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is known as the [Meyers singleton](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/C-plus-plus-In-Theory-The-Singleton-Pattern-Part-I/4/) and they are lazy instantiated.

There are some considerations:

- the singletons will be destroyed at the end of the program in the reverse order in which they are created, so there can be dependency issues.
- C++03 doesn't guarantee against race conditions in multithreaded environments.

Answer (score 10):

The `SingletonClass` constructor will not be called earlier than somenone calls the `Instance()` method.

Thus yes, it facilitates lazy initialization.

Comment: Interesting! Would have thought the opposite - i.e. static member instance is *always* there..!

Comment: @cacau As far I remember there's a guarantee in the language standard that a compiler has to implement this behavior. Should I look it up for you for mentioning?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The behaviour of *local static* (as static variables declared within a function are known) is indeed well specified. They are to be instantiated *the first time* flow of control passes through their declaration (thus if nested inside an `if` block, the first time the `if` branch is taken) and in case an exception is thrown during their initialization it will be re-attempted the next time flow of control passes through their declaration. Furthermore, in C++11 this initialization is thread-safe; though a number of compilers (gcc, clang, ...) already guaranteed that in C++03.