# Lazy evaluation with pair factory in C++

Tags: python, c++, design-patterns

I'm trying to implement `lazy` in C++ like in this Python example using decorators:

```
@lazy
@factory(Category)
def func(self):
    return self.__raw_data  # for building object include object type and **params
```

I found [Getting Lazy with C++](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/04/21/getting-lazy-with-c/) and [Lazy evaluation in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414243/lazy-evaluation-in-c) post but they haven't helped me. I don't understand how implement the lazy.

Comment: Do you mean this [`lazy` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lazy) and this [`lazy` decorator](http://pythonhosted.org/lazy/#lazy.lazy) ?

Comment: Hi Bakuriu, yep decorator. Example: class lazy(object):
        def __init__(self, function):
                self._function = function

        def __get__(self, instance, owner = None):
                if instance == None:
                        return self
                val = self._function(instance)
                setattr(instance, self._function.func_name, val)
                return val

Comment: It isn't clear what your specific problem is.

Comment: @n.m. hi. Ok, sorry for bad explanation. I want don`t create object while it not need. I stored raw data which transfer into constructor but not immediately. While object not need it just storaged (lazy) for create object in future and data for transfer in constructor. I want create objects to demand. How implement this on Python I know but C++ porting difficult for me.

Comment: @Bakuriu yep how decorator.

Comment: you mean something like this ??:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252296/lazy-initialization-with-singleton-pattern

Comment: @basav thanks for answer maybe this is solution of my problem.