# C++ Function with side-effect used at file scope, accesses singleton

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, abstract-factory, factory-method

I've written a class with the following static method:

```
MyMap& Manager::GetMap( void )
{
    static MyMap* factories = new MyMap();

    return ( *factories );
}
```

Where "MyMap" is a typedef for:

```
unordered_map<string, function<Base* ( Dependency& d )>>
```

There are also a variety of types derived from Base e.g.

```
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1( Dependency& d );
};
```

Consider the following usage.

I define the following in an implementation file for Derived1:

```
#include "Derived1.h"
#include "Manager.h"

int RegisterDerived1( void )
{
    Manager::GetMap()["Test"] = []( Dependency& d ){ return new Derived1( d ); };

    return 0;
}

int Reg = RegisterDerived1();
```

You can't call functions at file scope, but you can assign the return value of a function to a global variable even if that function has side effects. Hence, by the time that "Manager" is in use the "MyMap" will contain string/function pairs for various derived types of "Base" (so far). The intent is that new derived types of "Base" register themselves with "Manager", able to construct instances of that type and select which type based on a name.

I'm wondering if this represents safe behaviour and/or if there are alternative implementations to get the desired effect?

I've been made aware of this article that proposes a generic registration object that takes the above pair in its constructor and does the registering, a static instance of which is then defined for each class to be registered.

http://accu.org/index.php/journals/597

Comment: Seems that you are basically asking "Lazy Initialization" and the other code related things are not much relevant. Do you feel that, this post answers your Q: [Lazy initialization with singleton pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21252296/514235). If yes, then it can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @iammilind I'm clear on the behaviours of the singleton implementation, which is what I think that question is about. I just included the other bits for context. What I'm less clear on are the implications of using the above free function at file scope. It feels like a Bad Thing, since I need to work around a limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is fine.

A few things you may want to consider:

1. returning raw pointers is a bad idea - use unique_ptr instead.
2. Did you really want the Dependency& reference to be non-const?
3. Hide the internal implementation. There's no need for users to know (or care) that it's an unordered_map.

A slightly modified version with inline comments for you to consider:

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct Base
{
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Dependency
{

};

struct Manager
{
  // I notice that Depdendency& is not const. Was that what you wanted?
  using factory_function = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Base> ( Dependency& d )>;

  // public registration function hides internal implementation of map
  static bool register_function(const std::string ident, factory_function f)
  {
    return GetMap().emplace(std::move(ident), std::move(f)).second;
  }

  // public create function hides internal implementation of map
  // returns a unique_ptr - much better!
  static std::unique_ptr<Base> create(const std::string& ident, Dependency& d)
  {
    // this will throw an exception if the factory does not exist.
    // another implementation could substitute a known version of Base,
    // for example. But now it's under your control and the user does
    // not have to think about it.
    return GetMap().at(ident)(d);
  }

  private:

  using MyMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, factory_function>;

  // private map implementation. In future we may want to add a mutex
  // (in case the map can be dynamically updated?)
  // so let's encapsulate
  static MyMap& GetMap()
  {
    // no need for new here. Static variables are cleanly destructed at
    // the end of the program, and initialised the first time the code
    // flows over them.
    static MyMap _map;
    return _map;
  }
};

struct Derived1 : Base
{
  Derived1(Dependency&) {}
};

// now we don't need to care about Manager's implementation.
// this is better - we are decoupled.
bool derived1_registered = Manager::register_function("Derived1", 
                                                    [](Dependency& d)
                                                    {
                                                      return std::make_unique<Derived1>(d);
                                                    });

int main()
{
  Dependency d;
  auto p = Manager::create("Derived1", d);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, there are non-const methods I'm interested in on that Dependency class. Points 1 & 3 are well-taken, though. Any thoughts on the use of the free function in that way?

Comment: the free function is absolutely fine. You could even templatise it if you wanted so you only have to write it once.